# p5 can't find variable masterVolume

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js, volume

I [added p5.sound.js as instructed](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.sound/masterVolume), and assured it was in the correct place. I try to call:

```
masterVolume(1.0, 0.05, 0)
```

And it gives me the error. What is the deal?

Here is the complete page of the code that fails:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
    body { 
    margin: 0; 
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    }
    canvas { display: block; }
    .green {
        color:#219900;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="js/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/p5.sound.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    masterVolume(1.0, 0.05, 0)
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please also share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the error you got?

Comment: The error is "Can't find variable 'masterVolume'". The example is the code in my question.

Comment: It would be better if you could show us the context, like the js file (or part of it) in which you called masterVolume(), where did you put the p5.sound.js library and how did you include it, etc. With the current information, it's impossible for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, I included the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call `masterVolume`p5js `setup` must be called first.

Try putting the call to masterVolume in a function that will run in or after setup.

```
function setup() {
   // try the call here
   masterVolume(1.0, 0.05, 0);
}
function draw(){
   // or try the call here or in any p5js method
   masterVolume(1.0, 0.05, 0);
}
```