# J5 - JavaScript can't find variable "strokeCap"

Tags: javascript, variables, stroke, generative

I'm trying to get into generative Art and using for the first time p5.js for that. Now, I've tried to follow a guide to understand the process. I did exactly how the guide told me to do so, now I'm trying to figure out why I do have an error. The error is "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: strokeCap" I'm not really sure, why it does say can't find variable. Please help me out! I'd be very thankful.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop()
  colorMode(HSL)
}

function draw() {
  background("antiquewhite");
}
 let loops = 5;
 while (loops--) {
    strokeCap(SQUARE);
  strokeWeight(random(50));
  stroke(random(0, 50), random(0, 100), random(0, 100));
  line(random(50,350),random(50,350),random(50,350),random(50,350));
}

function mousePressed(){
  saveCanvas("outputSave","png")
}
```

Comment: strokeCap looks like a function here. Where are you getting the SQUARE from?

Comment: https://processing.org/reference/strokeCap_.html

Comment: You have a brace in the wrong spot. Move the `while` loop into the `draw` function instead of the global scope. Same fundamental problem as [p5 can't find variable masterVolume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439955/p5-cant-find-variable-mastervolume) -- all p5 functions need to be called only after `setup()` gets a chance to run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [p5 can't find variable masterVolume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439955/p5-cant-find-variable-mastervolume)